# Effectively joining aggregated data back to raw data in order to trace all the raw data that was used to compute the aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some raw data like so:

```
rawId| Name | Quantity| AggId
-----|------|---------|------
1    | Foo  |    10   | NULL
2    | Foo  |    20   | NULL
3    | Foo  |    30   | NULL
4    | Bar  |    40   | NULL
5    | Bar  |    50   | NULL
6    | Bar  |    60   | NULL
```

I want to aggregate them:

```
SELECT name, sum(quantity)
FROM foobar
GROUP BY name
```

And store these results somwhere:

```
AggId| Name | Quantity
-----|------|---------
1    | Foo  |    60
2    | Bar  |    150
```

My goal here is to be able to trace which records from the raw table were used to compute the aggregation in the aggregated table. In other words, I want to update all the `AggId` values for `foo` in the raw table to `1`, and all the `AggId` values for `bar` in the raw table to `2`.

Currently I'm joining the aggregated back to the raw on the grouped columns to find which `aggIds` are associated to which `rawIds`:

```
SELECT a.aggI r.rawId
FROM agg a JOIN raw r ON (a.name = r.name)
```

---

Is there a better way to accomplish this? For example, perhaps through an analytic function?

```
SELECT rawId, name, quantity, 
    SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY name) grouped_qty
FROM raw;
```

Results in

```
rawId| Name | Quantity| grouped_qty
-----|------|---------|------
1    | Foo  |    10   | 60
2    | Foo  |    20   | 60
3    | Foo  |    30   | 60
4    | Bar  |    40   | 60
5    | Bar  |    50   | 60
6    | Bar  |    60   | 60
```

It would be nice if I could get the analytic function to generate a sequence Id for the aggregated set; but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Does your table have any concept of history?  What's stopping someone from inserting or updating a value in that table resulting in a different `SUM` after you've collected the aggregates?

Comment: @Siyual It has some concept of a history; for example there is a `batch_id` column, and all the aggregations are also grouped across the `batch_id`. New records that need to be processed will always occur in another `batch_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want?

```
SELECT name, sum(quantity), listagg(foobar.rawid, ',')
FROM foobar
GROUP BY name;
```

This will include a list of the raw ids that go into each row.  Do note that there is a limit of 4000 characters on the length of the `listagg()` column.

Comment: He wants a number that increments for each name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want DENSE_RANK() if you leave out the partition by it will use the entire result set:

```
SELECT rawId, name, quantity, 
    SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY name) grouped_qty,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) as name_rank
FROM raw;
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: The question is tagged with Oracle - perhaps you should link to the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions052.htm#SQLRF00633) rather than SQL server.

Comment: @MT0 -- please change it if you know of oracle documentation that is as clear.  This is one of the best explanations of the different windowing functions I've ever found.  Both platforms are based on the same SQL Standard so it should be the same.